# ReportViewer & SSRS RDL Right-to-Left Export

Tags: asp.net, reporting-services, reportviewer, right-to-left, rdl

I am working on an ASP.Net project where we use SSRS RDL reports with the ReportViewer control.

The project is in Arabic language so the layout should be right to left.

I managed to display right to left reports in the ReportViewer using CSS `direction` on the rendered HTML of the report, but I'm having trouble controlling the report export direction.

I googled around but I could not find anything that can control the exported file.

**Solutions I tried:**

- Using a Matrix in the RDL with `LayoutDirection` set to `RTL`.
- Reversing the order of the fields and the tables of the RDL.
- Setting the report page's Culture and UICulture to ar-JO/ar-SA but it did not change anything.

So if anyone has any solution to achieve the RTL layout of the report and of the exported file, it'll be much appreciated.

Any solution using **C#/VB.Net/SSRS/ReportViewer/Configs/CSS/Javascript** is more that welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Tested:
set every textbox's `direction` property to `RTL`. Worked for me.